# How to optimize code in the ck editor using scripts?

Tags: javascript

I am using CK editor on my website and recently noted that it's creating unnecessary spans in it. See the reference image attached:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ8Q2.png

You can check it should not create different spans to add inline CSS. For more details you can also check this URL:
https://www.ibtindia.com/ssc-cgl-notification-exam-date

Please, anyone, suggest to me how to shorten this code with help of any script.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (and in fact, all of the Stack Exchange Network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which require users to go off-site to get more information are not useful to future visitors, particularly once the off-site resource changes. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move enough code into the question so we know what you're asking without needing to go off-site to find out. Please see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428) for more details.